# REF_CURSOR type is not supported when used in Java code to call stored procedures with cursor output parameter in SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, mssql-jdbc

We have a requirement in our project to call the stored procedure created in SQL Server with one input parameter and one cursor output parameter.
When I tried to call the stored procedure from Java code (code given below) using tyes.REF_CURSOR for cursor output parameter, we get error on running the server as 'REF_CURSOR' is not supported.

We are using the latest JDBC driver for SQL Server (version 12.2).

Java sample code:

```
 CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{ call get_employee_by_name(?,?) }");
 cs.setString(1, "mk");
 cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.REF_CURSOR);
 cs.execute();
 ResultSet resultSet = (ResultSet) cs.getObject(2);
while (resultSet.next()) {
}
```

Getting following error on running the server:

```
REF_CURSOR is not supported.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: REF_CURSOR is not supported.
```

I tried the ideas suggested in various stackoverflow questions but no luck.

The procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_employee_by_name
    @p_name varchar(max), 
    @CUR_OUT cursor VARYING OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET @CUR_OUT = CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY 
    FOR SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE
    WHERE NAME LIKE @p_name + '%';
END
GO
```

Comment: What does your procedure look like? Sounds pretty strange to use cursor for outputting data from a procedure.

Comment: Hi James, below is the procedure that I call using Java code.

CREATE PROCEDURE get_employee_by_name
        @p_name varchar(max),
        @CUR_OUT cursor VARYING  OUTPUT
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET @CUR_OUT = CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY  FOR
      SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE NAME LIKE @p_name + '%';

 

    END
GO
```

Comment: Ref cursor is an oracle thing. Why do you need cursor, just output the result itself

Comment: Well, [Support cursor out parameters #98](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/98) from the mssql-jdbc team says "nope."